# При попытке вычислить сумму бесконечного ряда возникли трудности

Tags: c++, for, while, ряды

Дали задание в университете, вычислить сумму бесконечного ряда. Попробовал произвести операцию через цикл for, но возникает ошибка "Вызвано исключение по адресу...". 
Код представлен ниже:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int Fact(int n) {
    if (n < 0) 
{
        return 0;
}

    else if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    else if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }

    return n * Fact(n - 1);
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    double x;

    cout << "Введите x (0.1 <= x <= 1): ";
    cin >> x;
    if (x < 0.1 || x > 1) {
        cout << "Неверно введенное число. Попробуйте ещё раз ((0.1 <= x <= 1): ";
            cin >> x;
    }
    double f;
    while (x >= 0.1 && x <= 1) {
        for (int n = 1;n++ ;)
        {
            x = pow(x, 2 * n);
            cout << 1 + x / Fact(2 * n) << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Причем если убрать n-ки в возведении x в квадрат и в значении факториала (в функции main), то код запускается без проблем. Вообщем запутался конкретно, помогите разобраться. Сам текст задания приведу в скриншоте.
[[image: Задание на выполнение]]
[image: Ошибка "Исключение не обработано"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если внимательно разобрать, то будет ясно, что в данном ряде каждый член формируется умножением предыдущего члена на `x ^ 2 / ((n + 1) * (n + 2))`, а  чтобы получить указанную точность, то последный член должен быть меньше этого значения. И не нужно отдельно считать факториал, а все упрощается до такого:

```
constexpr double e = 0.000001; //точность
double x = 0.6,     
       m = 1, // последный член
       res = m; 
int n = 0; 
while (m > e ) {
    m *= x * x / ((n + 1) * (n + 2));
    res += m;
    n += 2;     
}    
cout << setprecision(7) << res << endl << res + m;
```

Comment: А что setprecision() выполняет в данном коде?

Comment: @Anatolb, при выводе по умолчанию выводятся 6 знаков.   setprecision() устанавливает количество знаков, которые должны быть выведены. Читайте раздел " манипуляторы потоков"

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 1):

Проверять условие нужно с помощью **if** а не **while**.
У вас огромный цикл **for** на 2 миллиарда. Как-то исправьте. :

```
while (x >= 0.1 && x <= 1) { ***

        for (int n = 1;n++ ;)  ***

        {
            x = pow(x, 2 * n);
```

Функция  **Fact** рекурсивная, будет кушать память стека очень быстро. Стек закончится. Нужно переписать её на циклический вариант с помощью **for**. Желательно использовать предыдущее значение, тогда останется легче умножать.

Comment: Цикл for для факториала прописывать в функции main, a если нет, то как его объявлять тогда?